# Why do I get duplicate text with "paste" event on textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea id="source" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txarea = document.getElementById('source');
        txarea.addEventListener('paste', function(){
            let text = txarea.value;
            console.log(text);
            let replace_text = text.replace(/\n/g, ' ')
            console.log(replace_text);
            txarea.value = replace_text;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy some text with line break `\n`, for example

```
abc
ef
```

Then repeat: `Control + A` + `Control + V`. Then you can see there are more and more texts coming up each time.

I tried to add a `debugger` and check what's going on. But after I `step over` the last statement, it just becomes a mess.

What's wrong?

Comment: the same happens copying-pasting only one line, e.g. `abc`

Comment: @user2342558 Hmm. I don't get duplicate text with one line text, as long as there's no line break. For example, `abc` and `abc de` are fine with me. I am using Chrome Ubuntu v77.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break down the test case and how it interacts with your code.

1. User selects all text in the text area.
2. User initiates a "paste".
3. Before the paste takes place, your callback fires.
4. Your callback replaces the contents of the textarea with new, modified contents. (Replacing newlines with spaces.)
5. Because you have entirely replaced the textarea's contents with new contents, the user's initial text selection is no longer valid. **So the effective cursor position is now at the end of the new, replaced contents.**
6. The paste happens, adding new text to the end of the textarea's contents.

In step #5, if the text wasn't modified (i.e. it didn't have newlines to begin with) then the selection remains valid and the paste happens as a replace instead of an append.

---

I *think* that what you are trying to do is this:

1. Detect that the user is attempting to paste some text.
2. Modify the text before it gets pasted in. (By replacing newlines with spaces.)

---

You can find out what text is being pasted in using the [paste event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event), i.e.:

```
let paste = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text');
```

But you don't want to just replace the contents of the textarea with this pasted info, nor do you want to append it at the end. What if the user places the caret in the middle of the text and then hits ctrl+v?

Enter [`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

```js
var txarea = document.getElementById('source');
txarea.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let text = '';
  if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
    text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  } else if (window.clipboardData) {
    text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  }

  console.log(text);
  let replace_text = text.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
  console.log(replace_text);

  if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, replace_text);
  } else {
    document.execCommand('paste', false, replace_text);
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="source" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
</form>
```

---

Note: Firefox does not (at the time of writing) support 'insertText' or 'paste' commands on a `textarea` or `input` ([bug report 1220696](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696)), but it does support these commands on a `contenteditable` div.

Comment: Yes. I just figured out that I am changing the text before pasting executes. But why there's no unexpected text with e.g. `abc def` without line break?

Comment: @Rick i'm not sure i understand your question. your code essentially removed newlines from all existing text before pasting in the new text, and then allowed the new text to be pasted in (unmodified) after your function exited.

Comment: @Rick notice the `e.preventDefault();` at the top of my function. i think that might help you understand the part that doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: @Rick i've re-worked my answer a bit. does that address your question? feel free to ask for more clarification.

Comment: Yes I debug again and found out the problem. But I don't know why for one line text e.g. `abc`, it doesn't get extra result. Anyway, I did it wrong.

Comment: if the textarea's contents doesn't have newlines, then the `let replace_text = text.replace(/\n/g, ' ')` doesn't actually do anything, so the user's selection remains valid. that's why single-line text does a replace rather than an append.

Comment: Sorry @Woodrow Barlow. I was too tired to reply yesterday.. I read your answer carefully today and I found this is important "In step #5, if the text wasn't modified (i.e. it didn't have newlines to begin with) then the selection remains valid and the paste happens as a replace instead of an append.", which explains why text doesn't append if the content doesn't change. Where did you find that description(the `1 - 6`  you said about how paste interacts)?  I looked through MDN and did not get a clue. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Rick it's just from experience and experimentation. :) it's not defined in any standard, it's an implementation-specific detail. it's conceivable that some browsers might behave differently. but, intuitively, put yourself in the shoes of the people who write the browser software: if some text is highlighted, and then javascript swaps out the text with something different, should the browser try to figure out how to re-highlight the new text? is there really a way to do that in a way that's predictable? probably not. so the next best thing is just to put the cursor at the beginning or the end.